# Django - dynamic change form fields

Tags: django

I have a simple form to add a website to database. This is my site model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    category1 = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='+',)
    subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(
        'Subcategory',
        chained_field='category',
        chained_model_field='category',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    # importuje zmienione TextFields widgets.py
    keywords = MyTextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
    url = models.URLField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=(('Basic',
                                                     'Basic'), ('Premium', 'Premium')))

subcategory1 = ChainedForeignKey(
    'Subcategory',
    chained_field='category1',
    chained_model_field='category1',
    related_name='subcategory1',
    show_all=False,
    auto_choose=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "%s/%i" % (self.subcategory.slug, self.id)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Sites"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Forms.py

```
class SiteAddFormFull(forms.ModelForm):

    url = forms.URLField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'description', 'keywords', 'group', 'category1','subcategory1')
```

I would like to change my form by adding fields 'Category1', 'Subcategory1' after user choose value in group field ('Premium'). Form should reload itself and show those fields. Before choosing 'Premium' fields 'Category1', 'Subcategory1' should be invisible. How can I achieve that?

In my forms.py I added:

```
widgets = {'category1': forms.HiddenInput(), 'subcategory1':
                   forms.HiddenInput()}
```

In my .js file I try to show those fields but it doesn't work:

```
$(":hidden").show();
// $("#id_category1".show() and other posibilities
```

In my page soure I have

```
<input id="id_category1" name="category1" type="hidden" /><input id="id_subcategory1" name="subcategory1" type="hidden" />
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: load all the data and use javascript in the client side to achieve what you want or do some ajax calls to the server to load data every time the field change

Comment: in forms init function  set those form attribute as hidden once you choose premium with the help of js  remove the hidden attribute

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `HiddenInput` for categories. Just hide it with jquery and show it on select change event.

```
<select id="group">
  <option value="First">First</option>
  <option value="Premium">Premium</option>
  <option value="Second">second</option>
</select>
<select id="category1">
  <option value="First">First</option>
  <option value="Second">second</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#category1').hide();
    $('#group').change(function(e) {
  var group = $(this).val();
  if (group == 'Premium'){
    $('#category1').show();
  } else {
    $('#category1').hide();
  }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fwfm9byy/1/